# IO error after I change my template settings

Tags: django, ioerror

Im new to django, I am trying to make an e-commerce site. Since I always received errors each time I try to do makemigrations I have removed TEMPLATE_DIRS and included it to TEMPLATES settings are stated below:

```
     TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", 
     'templates', ), )

     TEMPLATES = [
    {
     'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        (os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", 'templates',), )
```

after I change it my site returned to this kind of error, what could be the problem

```
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/admin/
Django Version: 1.11.6
Exception Type: IOError
Exception Value:    
[Errno 22] Invalid argument: u"C:\\trydjango\\src\\
('C:\\trydjango\\static\\templates',)\\admin\\index.html"
```

UPDATE :

```
 BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
```

Comment: may be you need to comment the line with `'templates', ), )`

Comment: which django version?

Comment: If you are creating an e-commerce site, then you can use django-oscar. https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar

Comment: @MohammadMustaqeem Django 1.11.6

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra level - a tuple - inside your dirs setting. You should remove it.

```
 TEMPLATES = [
   {
      'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
      'DIRS': [
          os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", 'templates'),
      ]
   }
 ]
```

Comment: I did changed it thanks, though the IO error still reflects on                               [Errno 22] Invalid argument: u"C:\\trydjango\\src\\('C:\\trydjango\\static\\templates',)\\admin\\index.html"

Comment: Just posted an Update for the BASE_DIR